VS Code Rest Client doesn't work with Nuxt 3 server routes
I created a simple Nuxt app npx nuxi@latest init
I then created an api route. i.e. a file test.ts in server/api with the basic stub
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  // ... Do whatever you want here
})

npm run dev
The endpoint works fine from a browser. I can just type http://localhost:3000/api/test into the url bar in the browser and I get the expected response.
The endpoint also works fine from PostMan
But if you try to access it from a .http file using the Rest Client (Huachao Mao) in Visual Studio Code, it says the connection refused.
Is this a bug?
Is there a workaround?
Am I missing something? (I've been using this plugin for years successfully with every other server stack.

which version of node?

Node version 20.12.0

Here is where you should ask the question: https://github.com/Huachao/vscode-restclient/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc
